# Using autograd.grad() as a parameter for a loss function (pytorch)

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

I want to compute the gradient between two tensors in a net. The input X tensor is sent through a set of convolutional layers which give me back and output Y tensor.

I’m creating a new loss and I would like to know the MSE between gradient  of norm(Y) w.r.t. each element of X. Here the code:

```
# Staring tensors
X = torch.rand(40, requires_grad=True)
Y = torch.rand(40, requires_grad=True)

# Define loss
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()

#Make some calculations
V = Y*X+2

# Compute the norm
V_norm = V.norm()

# Computing gradient to calculate the loss
for i in range(len(V)):
    if i == 0:
        grad_tensor = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=V_norm, inputs=X[i])
    else:
        grad_tensor_ = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=V_norm, inputs=X[i])
        grad_tensor = torch.cat((grad_tensor, grad_tensor_), dim=0)

# Grund truth
gt = grad_tensor * 0 + 1

#Loss
loss_g = loss_fn(grad_tensor, gt)
print(loss_g)
```

Unfortunately, I’ve been making tests with torch.autograd.grad(), but I could not figure out how to do it. I get teh following error: `RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph. Set allow_unused=True if this is the desired behavior.`

Setting `allow_unused=True` gives me back `None` which is not an option. Not sure how to compute the loss between the gradients and the norm. Any idea about how to code this loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving mentioned error because you are trying to feed a slice of tensor `X`: `X[i]` to `grad()`, and it is going to be considered as a separate tensor, outside of your main computational graph. Not sure, but seems it returns new tensor while performing slicing.

But you don't need a for loop to compute gradients:

Code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

torch.manual_seed(42)

# Create some data.
X = torch.rand(40, requires_grad=True)
Y = torch.rand(40, requires_grad=True)

# Define loss.
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()

# Do some computations.
V = Y * X + 2

# Compute the norm.
V_norm = V.norm()

print(f'V norm: {V_norm}')

# Computing gradient to calculate the loss
grad_tensor = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=V_norm, inputs=X)[0]  # [0] - Because grad returs tuple, so we need to unpack it
print(f'grad_tensor:\n {grad_tensor}')

# Grund truth
gt = grad_tensor * 0 + 1

loss_g = loss_fn(grad_tensor, gt)
print(f'loss_g: {loss_g}')
```

Output:

```
V norm: 14.54827

grad_tensor:
    tensor([0.1116, 0.0584, 0.1109, 0.1892, 0.1252, 0.0420, 0.1194, 0.1000, 0.1404,
            0.0272, 0.0007, 0.0460, 0.0168, 0.1575, 0.1097, 0.1120, 0.1168, 0.0771,
            0.1371, 0.0208, 0.0783, 0.0226, 0.0987, 0.0512, 0.0929, 0.0573, 0.1464,
            0.0286, 0.0293, 0.0278, 0.1896, 0.0939, 0.1935, 0.0123, 0.0006, 0.0156,
            0.0236, 0.1272, 0.1109, 0.1456])

loss_g: 0.841885
```

**Loss between the grads and the norm**

You also mentioned that you want to compute loss between the gradients and the norm, it is possible. And there are two possible options of it:

You want to include your loss calculation to your computational graph, in this case use:

```
loss_norm_vs_grads = loss_fn(torch.ones_like(grad_tensor) * V_norm, grad_tensor)
```

You want just to compute loss and you don't want to start backward path from the loss, in this case don't forget to use `torch.no_grad()`, otherwise `autograd` will track this changes and add loss computation to your computational graph.

```
with torch.no_grad():
    loss_norm_vs_grads = loss_fn(torch.ones_like(grad_tensor) * V_norm, grad_tensor)
```