# PyTorch Autograd Differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent, autograd

I'm trying to improve a CNN I made by implementing a weighted loss method described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.09050.pdf). To do this, I looked into [this notebook](https://github.com/danieltan07/learning-to-reweight-examples/blob/master/Learning%20to%20Reweight%20Examples%20for%20Robust%20Deep%20Learning.ipynb) which implements the pseudo-code of the method described in the paper.

When translating their code to my model, I ran into the error `RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph. Set allow_unused=True if this is the desired behavior` when using `torch.autograd.grad()`.

My code and the error is in the second to last line:

```
for epoch in range(1): #tqdm(range(params['epochs'])):
  model.train()
  text_t, labels_t = next(iter(train_iterator))
  text_t = to_var(text_t, requires_grad=False)
  labels_t = to_var(labels_t, requires_grad=False)
  dummy = L2RWCNN(INPUT_DIM, EMBEDDING_DIM, N_FILTERS, FILTER_SIZES, OUTPUT_DIM, 
                DROPOUT, PAD_IDX)
  dummy.state_dict(model.state_dict())
  dummy.cuda()
  y_f_hat = dummy(text_t)
  cost = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_f_hat.squeeze(), labels_t, reduce = False)
  eps = to_var(torch.zeros(cost.size()))
  l_f_meta = torch.sum(cost * eps)
  dummy.zero_grad()
  num_params = 0
  grads = torch.autograd.grad(l_f_meta, (dummy.params()), create_graph = True)
  with torch.no_grad():
    for p, grad in zip(dummy.parameters(), grads):
      tmp = p - params['lr'] * grad
      p.copy_(tmp)
  text_v, labels_v = next(iter(valid_iterator))
  y_g_hat = dummy(text_v)
  l_g_meta = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_g_hat.squeeze(), labels_v, reduce = False)
  l_g_meta = torch.sum(l_g_meta)
  grad_eps = torch.autograd.grad(l_g_meta, eps, only_inputs=True)[0]
  print(grad_eps)
```

I think the error is because `eps` was not in any previous `torch.autograd.grad()` calls. I tried the suggested solution of setting `allow_unused=True` but that resulted in a `None` value. I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763081/using-autograd-grad-as-a-parameter-for-a-loss-function-pytorch) to find a solution, but the method that fixed the problem here (don't slice the tensors) doesn't work for me because I'm not passing in any partial variables. I also tried setting `create_graph = False` in my first `autograd.grad()` call, but that didn't fix the issue. Does anyone have a solution?

[My full code if that's needed](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aY7XlgUClEe5Ldeu8DjSsxuj9sXTtRw4?usp=sharing)

EDIT:
Created a new post with a different phrasing to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67008171/pytorch-backwards-automatic-diff-with-weighted-loss)

Comment: related: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-one-of-the-differentiated-tensors-appears-to-not-have-been-used-in-the-graph-set-allow-unused-true-if-this-is-the-desired-behavior/43679/8 does this help you?